# Is the * operator or just shows variables type?

Tags: pointers

I have read in many places, some writers says, that * is operator and some other says it isn't operator, it's jut shows that the variable have pointer type.

Comment: `A pointer is a data type that "points to" another value stored in memory using its address.` from stack tag, i trust on stack tags

Comment: You should add a tag with the language. Without that it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It has three meanings (assuming you're talking about C or C++):

```
int* p; // Here it shows the type of p.
*p;     // Here it's an operator that dereferences p.
3 * 4;  // Here it's the multiplication operator.
```

Answer (score 0):

One assumes you are talking C/C++.

The * can be an operator - i.e. multiplication

Or can deference a pointer.

Depends on context